# Retrieving a List type field from an Entity in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have an Entity in which one of the fields is of `List<String>` type. Then, I want to retrieve that specific list field from a *Dao*'s query. However, the obtained result is not the expected one as shown below:

Entity:

```
@Entity
data class MyModel(@PrimaryKey val id: String,
                   val listField: List<String>)
```

I have a `TypeConverter` to support the *List* type in `Room` as follows:

```
@TypeConverter
fun stringToList(value: String): List<String>? {
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<List<String>>(value, type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun listToString(list: List<String>): String {
    return Gson().toJson(list)
}
```

Finally, I have a *Dao* with the following queries:

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(model: MyModel)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE id = :id")
    fun getMyModel(id: String): MyModel?

    @Query("SELECT listField FROM MyModel WHERE id = :id")
    fun getListField(id: String): List<String>?
}
```

The results obtained are the following:

```
val myModel = MyModel("myId", listOf("item1", "item2"))

myDao.insert(myModel)

val retrievedModel = myDao.getMyModel("myId") //Returns correct model - Correct

val listField = myDao.getListField("myId") //Returns ["[item1, item2]"] - Wrong
```

So, when trying to retrieve the *listField*, instead of returning the actual list, it returns a list containing a string version of the *listField* value.

Is it possible to retrieve the desired list field in `Room`?

Comment: Why don't you use the `listField` field of your `MyModel` object?

Comment: @underoid
Yes, I can just retreive the entire model and then use the Model's listField.
However, I was just wondering why retrieving just the listField does not work at all. If it is due to any Room's limitation or something, as I think it should be possible to do so.
So it is just to understand if there is a reason why it is not working.

Comment: @JeelVankhede
Yes, otherwise I would not be able to retrieve the entire model in the first query

Comment: @JeelVankhede
It made no difference.
However, even without ```@JvmStatic``` were accessible, as otherwise it would not let me insert or retrieve the entire model, as it would not know how to store the *List* type

Comment: Okay, try providing `TypeToken` inside `listToString()`.

Comment: It is interesting, as I have tested `TypeConverter` is not used at all for `List<String>` return type. It can also be seen in the generated file `MyDao_Impl` that `dataTypeConverter` object is not used. Creating a new simple class with less fields in it not to retrieve the huge object can be a solution for that purpose.

Comment: Change `getListField` return type to String and convert it manually with `stringToList`.